# MS Graph API - access shared mailbox (application permission)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I use GraphServiceClient (ClientCredentialProvider) to access a mailbox. It works fine.

I would like to access its shared mailboxes. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks,

AU

Comment: Added the answer below. Consider upvoting it and accepting it as answer. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, i tested with Microsoft Graph Explorer. You need to add/consent the required permissions for the user on Graph Explorer by selecting the permissions from "Settings Gear" on left side. Select Mail.Read.Shared from the list of permissions and consent it.
[image]

On successful, you can access the shared mailbox and its messages like the following:-
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{sharedmailboxmailaddress}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bsharedmailboxmailaddress%7D/messages)
[image]

Comment: Thank you, is it Delegated or Application permission? I am looking for the App permission.